# Sending variables to a php script for database from java script

Tags: javascript, php

First, I have looked at just about every other question here on this subject but I can't find anything like I need. I'm trying to send the userId for one signal to a PHP script to put it in a database. I have tried many different versions of this.

Here is the script that does send to the PHP script and put's it in the database but the userId is NULL.

```
//Secondly this will check when subscription changed
    OneSignal.push(function() {
        OneSignal.on('subscriptionChange', function (isSubscribed) {
            if(isSubscribed==true){
                OneSignal.getUserId().then(function(userId) {
                    useragentid = userId;
                    var theuserid = userId
                }).then(function(){
                 // this is custom function
                // here you can send post request to php file as well.
                    OneSignalUserSubscription(useragentid);
                    //document.cookie = "theplayerID="+useragentid+";";

                    var theuserid = OneSignalUserSubscription(useragentid);
                });

window.location.href = "sub_post.php?userId=" + theuserid + "&sponsor=josh"; 

                document.getElementById('successtext').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('unsubscribe').style.display = '';
                document.getElementById('subscribe').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else if(isSubscribed==false){
                OneSignal.getUserId().then(function(userId) {
                    useragentid = userId;
                });
                document.getElementById('unsubscribe').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('subscribe').style.display = '';
            }
            else{
                console.log('Unable to process the request');
            }
        });
    });
```

The part to look at is this:

```
window.location.href = "sub_post.php?userId=" + useragentid + "&sponsor=josh";
```

You will notice that I have a `var theuserid = userId` in there. When I replace `useragentid` with `theuserid` in that one line, it don't send anything over, it's like it ignores the entire statement. But when I use `useragentid` it does send to the PHP script but it's NULL. Why would it work with `useragentid` but not with `theuserid`? Is it because one is global and the other is not? Would that cause it to completely ignore the statement when using `theuserid` because it's not global?

I'm hoping someone can help with this without the entire code because I'm thinking it's a simple java script error that I'm causing so I'm thinking that the entire code is really not relevent.

Comment: In javascript, not having a `var`, `let`, or `const` with the variable makes an implicit global reference, so `useragentid ` has global scope, but `var theuserid` has scope only within the function where defined, and is not available to the href assignment, which is why it is null. See [this info](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/beware-of-unsafe-implicit-globals-in-javascript-f370ccca8fdb) (there are other references, but that is one)

Comment: @PaulT. I may have confused the statement. When I use "useragentid" it's NULL but it does send over to the PHP script. When I replace that with "theuserid" it just does not send to the PHP script, it's not just NULL it just does not send like it's ignoring the entire statement.

Comment: But you said: `When I replace useragentid with theuserid in that one line, it don't send anything over`? ... Anyway, before the `href` assignment, add a `console.log("sub_post.php?userId=" + theuserid + "&sponsor=josh");` ... and another with `useragentid` to see what the difference may show in the browser console.

Comment: Thank you @PaulT. and sorry for the confusion. Doing what you said, showed me how to fix it. I got it fixed now. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

```
OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId) {
window.location.href = "sub_post.php?userId=" + userId + "&sponsor=josh"; 
});
```

This allows me to get the userId again in a function and then send it to the PHP script which captures it successfully.